# Sulu: How do I determine, that the current page is the search page?

Tags: sulu

When I'm running a standard search, for example `/search?q=querystring` the available urls are pointing to the root:

```
// dump of the twig url variable:
array:1 [▼
  "de" => "/"
]
```

This is causing my menu to highlight the home link, which is of course not correct ;) - Is there a good way to distinguish the search page from the actual frontpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug for me but you can use `path` variable to check if its actually a page template e.g.

```
{% if path is defined %}
```

Don't let the content of the path variable confuse you its the location of the content page in the phpcr tree so it does not represent a url. In some cases it does match the url. In most cases the path variable is a good way to check if a page is a child of another page also if you use other resourcelocator strategies as the default tree one.

e.g. if you create a navigation:

```
{% for page in sulu_navigation_root_tree('main') %}
    {% set addClass = '' %}
    {% if page.path starts with path|default() %}
        {% set addClass = 'is-active-parent' %}
    {% elseif page.uuid == uuid|default() %}
        {% set addClass = 'is-active' %}
    {% endif %}

    {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```